# How to debug Entity Framework migration LoaderExceptions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to run `update-database` in an Entity Framework 5 project that runs on other machine.

I downloaded the code, rebuilt the project and when I run `update-database` I get an error like this:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindType[TBase](String typeName, Func`2 filter, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

I assume that this error is happening because some assembly is missing on my environment, or maybe because of an incompatible assembly being found in the GAC. But whitout knowing wich type failed to load, I'm in the dark so it's a very difficult issue to debug.

How can I find out which type or assembly failed to load? The message says to "retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information" but how can I do that, given the migration runs in the package manager console, and not in my own code?

Typing `$Error[0].Exception` in the console shows the exception message, but how can I list its other properties?

Comment: Did you try casting the Exception to System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException and access the LoaderExceptions property?

Comment: @user1908061 No, where I should do that? In the PowerShell command line? In a class file? How? This may be the answer, in this case I'd appreciate if you post it as an answer with a little more detail.

Comment: I ment typing it in the console, like you did with `$Error[0].Exception`, but this time casting the Exception to the correct type and accessing the `LoaderExceptions` property to get more information regarding the exact problem. But I'm glad you already solved the problem. :-)

Comment: Sounds good, but I couldn't do that, either because I couldn't find the right syntax or, I suspect, because the exception that surfaced was not the original exception and there was no InnerException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this could help you, but just throwing an idea...

You could try running the migration from the code - there you might get beter exception handling. e.g.

[EF Code First DbMigration without nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271445/ef-code-first-dbmigration-without-nuget)

```
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(new YourConfiguration());
migrator.Update(); // or update specific migrations..
```

You could also turn that via config - and even turn that on w/o recompiling (for production) - if you have logging/tracing enabled you might get some errors from it...

```
    <contexts>
        <context type="YourNS.YourContext, YourAssembly">
            <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[YourNS.YourContext, YourAssembly], [YourNS.YourConfiguration, YourAssembly]], EntityFramework" />
        </context>
    </contexts>

</entityFramework>
```

Comment: I created a new console application project, referencing my migration project and containing the code you posted. When it ran, I was able to see the exception and find out which assembly was failing to be loaded. Thank you.

Comment: I had no idea it'd work - but so glad it did :) you're welcome @FernandoCorreia