# .Net code first migration reflection issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, devforce

When running Update-Database in the package manager console of my solution, I receive the following error:

```
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target  database.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
    at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindType[TBase](String typeName, Func`2 filter, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
 Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

I read in other [similar stack overflow discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774247/how-to-debug-entity-framework-migration-loaderexceptions) that sometimes more information can be gained by running the update programatically and catching that exception, so I have tried this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774247/how-to-debug-entity-framework-migration-loaderexceptions
    DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
    migrator.Update();
}
```

The above code actually runs the update successfully without issues (as do the migrations when run by the web browser on application initialization) but the package manager still fails on the same Update-Database command with the same error. I've checked startup projects, default projects, reference copy-local settings, regenerating the ibmmx file, database restores, and run multiple visual studio/OS restarts. I've also tried accessing the exception information through powershell but haven't found anything. Does anyone know of a way to get more information about why the package manager operations are failing?

This same setup with the same underlying database states (different database servers, both on localhost) works without issues on another development machine, so it appears to be something specific to my setup or installation. Are there any other "gotchas" I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Update: I might have spoken too soon about the migrations working outside of the package manager. I just made one on the working dev machine, pulled it to my local machine, and found it doesn't work through the application initialization in the web browser or the package manager.

Comment: So the migration fails only on your machine but works on other dev machines?  Which versions of EntityFramework and DevForce are you running?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's correct. I'm running DevForce 2012 EDM Designer Excention for VS version 7.2.2.0, DevForce 2012 Templates version 7.2.2.0, and Entity Framework version 5.0.0.0.

Comment: I can't help with getting more detailed exception information, but I'd look for a "missing" assembly - maybe an assembly holding base entity classes or PostSharp.dll or IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Edm.EF5.dll. Since this is working on another machine, also compare the two environments for EF and DF versions and project structure.

Comment: So. This problem has continued for the last month or so after multiple restarts, environment wipes, updates, etc. However, I put my computer to sleep last night when it wasn't working, woke my computer up this morning, and now everything works. No code changes, local database changes, updates, or anything while the computer was asleep but now I can manage migrations again through the package manager. That's puzzling.