# Code First Migrations without NuGet

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

I'm wondering how I can use Entity Framework's Code First Migrations without using NuGet at all (so no commands via the package manager console).

I tried the following:

### Database-Context

```
public sealed class MyContext : DbContext
{
  private const string ConnectionStringName = "MyDatabase";

  public MyContext()
    : base(ConnectionStringName)
  {}

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    SetupMyModel(modelBuilder);
  }
}
```

### Migration-Configuration

```
public class MyMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
  public MyMigrationConfiguration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
  }
}
```

### Database-Initializer

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyMigrationConfiguration>());
```

### InitialDatabaseCreation Migration

```
public class InitialDatabaseCreation : DbMigration, IMigrationMetadata
{
  public override void Up()
  {
    CreateTable("dbo.MyModel",
      c => new
      {
        Id = c.Guid(false, true),
        SomeProperty = c.Int(false)
      })
      .PrimaryKey(x => x.Id);
  }

  public override void Down()
  {
    DropTable("dbo.MyModel");
  }

  public string Id
  {
    get { return "0001_InitialDatabaseCreation"; }
  }

  public string Source
  {
    get { return null; }
  }

  public string Target
  {
    get { return Id; }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I wrote a context, a migration configuration and the migration itself. 
For the Migration, I'm not sure, if I implemented the `IMigrationMetadata` correcly. For the Target I just use the id, because I don't want to have any automatic migrations or the ability to use the package manager console. I think, this should be fine here?

I set a breakpoint at the `Up` method and debugged it, but it does not stop there, which means it doesn't get executed.

Therefor I want to know how to use the EF Code First migrations when writing everything manually.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to avoid the Nuget console - Nuget's here, it's a reality, you'll struggle to get much done whilst avoiding it both now and in the future...

Comment: Well, it's just something I want to try and didn't achieve it yet :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Another point is (I forgot): The model is madeup with interfaces only and it seems, that the build into auto model generation does not work as expected.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271445/ef-code-first-dbmigration-without-nuget)