# How to manually (via code) apply DbMigration which was manually crafted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbmigrate

I manually created a class

```
  public class AddClientsTable : DbMigration, IMigrationMetadata
  {
        
    string IMigrationMetadata.Id
    {
      get { return "201611281757258_AddClientsTable"; }
    }

    string IMigrationMetadata.Source
    {
      get { return null; }
    }

    string IMigrationMetadata.Target
    {
      get { return "AddClientsTable-Migration"; }
    }

    public override void Up() {
      CreateTable("Clients", t => new {
          ClientId = t.Guid(name:"ClientId"),
          Name = t.String()
          })
      .PrimaryKey( t => t.ClientId, "ClientId")
      .Index( t => t.ClientId, "PK_Clients", true);
    }

    public override void Down() {
      DropIndex("Clients", "PK_Clients");
      DropTable("Clients");
    }

  }
```

and i want to apply it via code-first migrations *from code* like this :

```
      var migration = new AddClientsTable();
      migration.Up();
      context.RunMigration(migration);
```

which I stole from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767667/5767019) but when I run the code I'm getting this exception :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.CreateIndexOperation' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.HistoryOperation'.
```

`HistoryOperation` is the operation which updates `__MigrationHistory` table ?  so How do I do that via code ?

Am I missing something or the EntityFrameowrk `Update-Database` command does more than what I'm aware of ?

Comment: why exactly are you trying to do it by code again?

Comment: well, I don't use visual studio ( too slow on my very old machine ) to execute Update-Database command, I just use gvim to do code editing and I really want to be able to do Code-First Databse Migration just like that.

Comment: Do you have powershell? There are powershell commands for each of the database functions for entity-framework

Comment: yes, I'm on windows and I do have powershell, but the need for doing it in code comes from the fact that I need to apply same migrations on my users' machines so it'll be easier to migrate their local databases.

Comment: If you want to execute all new migrations using code first, try ```MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion``` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (sample here https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Libs/Context/Arma3BEClientContext.cs)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to cherry pick a migration and run it, because the migrations are cumulative and must be run in sequence. As such, you'd be better to run the equivalent of `update-database` powershell command at application startup.

Here's some code we use to do that:

In the `Configuration.cs` class constructor (this file was made when you `enable-migrations`)

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
```

then at app startup call the following method:

```
public static void ApplyDatabaseMigrations()
{
    //Configuration is the class created by Enable-Migrations
    DbMigrationsConfiguration dbMgConfig = new Configuration()
    {
        ContextType = typeof(MyDbContext) //+++++CHANGE ME+++++
    };
    using (var databaseContext = new MyDbContext()) //+++++CHANGE ME+++++
    {
        try
        {
            var database = databaseContext.Database;
            var migrationConfiguration = dbMgConfig;
            migrationConfiguration.TargetDatabase =
                new DbConnectionInfo(database.Connection.ConnectionString,
                                     "System.Data.SqlClient");
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationConfiguration);
            migrator.Update();
        }
        catch (AutomaticDataLossException adle)
        {
            dbMgConfig.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            var mg = new DbMigrator(dbMgConfig);
            var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(mg);
            string script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, null);
            throw new Exception(adle.Message + " : " + script);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution but was faced with another problem,
` string IMigrationMetadata.Target
    {
      get { return "AddClientsTable-Migration"; }
    }`
this field needs to be a `Base64` of the model (?), how can I generate it from code or from powershell ? I'm thinking of using powershell from comand line to generate the migrations and applying them using yoyr snipppet of code.

Comment: @Abdelghani This is what the `Add-Migration` command is for. Good luck navigating migrations without it.