# Dependency Injection into Entity Framework seed method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to inject dependencies into Configuration class of Entity Framework 6?

For example, like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyBaseContext>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Configuration(ILogger logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Home.DAL.Data.HomeBaseContext context)
    {
         //log something
    }
}
```

Or more general approach is to obtain possibility to inject code even inside migrations:

```
public partial class InitialMigration : DbMigration
{        
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public InitialMigration(ILogger logger)
    {            
         this._logger = logger;
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(...);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable(...);
    }
}
```

Where is DI initialization happens in Entity Framework 6 to define those bindings?

**UPDATE**

Im not asking about what I should use. Currently, Im using Ninject but that's out of the question, because whatever I use, I should be able to inject dependecies into constructor of migrations. Of courser if you write something like I wrote in example above it will just throw you exception about "no default constructor".

ILogger in above example is just simple example of dependency. Things go worse if you have IGeneratorService which will generate some data and you want to use this service to generate data for Seed method.

Comment: DI initialization should be handled by your DI framework.

Comment: How is this answer to any part of this question?

Comment: Have you tried using any DI frameworks?

Comment: Entity Framework does not use any DI container. Both those types (DbMigrationsConfiguration, DbMigration) are created using refleciton, so you cannot use constructor injection or similar approach to do that.

Comment: How do you run those migrations? Using `Update-Database`?

Comment: Its important to note that .NET doesn't have Dependency Injection built-in for .NET 4.5 and EF 6 so you have to use some other DI framework such as StructureMap, Ninject, etc. Starting with .NET Core and EF Core does .NET have Dependency Injection built in. If you want to use ILogger in your Configuration or InitialMigration partial classes, you can't use constructor injection as @Evk said. However, you can still pass ILoggerFactory to your constructor and instantiate ILogger instance using lLoggerFactory.Create() method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 suggests that you are using .NET Framework 4.6 or below and there is no dependency injection capability built-in for .NET 4.6 or below so you have to use third-party DI containers such as StructureMap, Ninject, etc. Those DI containers give you 3 ways to get dependency injection: through the constructor, setter, or interface.

I'm not entirely sure if its possible to use constructor injection to inject dependencies into `Configuration` or `InitialMigration` class, but I doubt it. Even if it is possible, you wouldn't be able to inject `ILogger` the way you describe in your question: `this._logger = logger` because ILogger is initialized using ILoggerFactory `Create()` method.

So, I don't think its possible to inject dependencies into your `Configuration` or `InitialMigration` classes using constructor injection in general.

If you want to use `ILogger` in your classes, the following code snippets should work:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyBaseContext>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Configuration(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this._logger = loggerFactory.Create("ConfigurationLogger");
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Home.DAL.Data.HomeBaseContext context)
    {
         //log something
         _logger.WriteInformation("Seeding data.");
    }
}

public partial class InitialMigration : DbMigration
{        
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public InitialMigration(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {            
         this._logger = loggerFactory.Create("InitialMigrationLogger");
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        _logger.WriteInformation("Create table.");
        CreateTable(...);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        _logger.WriteInformation("Drop table.");
        DropTable(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  Certainly not when trying to use update-database from the command line.  Remember that your DI container is registered at run time. There would be no services registered to be injected anywhere.  In addition to that EF is looking for a configuration file with a parameter-less constructor.  You can quickly test this yourself with the example from your question. You will get a "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Your.Assembly".

If you are specifically looking to perform some action from a service in your seed method then I would suggest looking into the runtime api that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271445/ef-code-first-dbmigration-without-nuget).

I use a console app in my projects that I can send commands to as part of my build pipeline when deploying.  You could easily use this approach within your actual code base.

```
private void RunMigrations()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting migrations...");
        var configuration = new Configuration
        {
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(_connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient")
        };
        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        dbMigrator.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("Migrations completed");

        //add your service here and do whatever you want.
    }

    private void Seed()
    {
        using (var MyContext = new MyContext(_connectionString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Seeding test data into database");
            //this is a custom seed method
            Initialize.Seed(_connectionString);
            Console.WriteLine("Seeding test data is complete");

            //add your service here and do whatever you want.
        }
    }
```